# how to maintaining session when using more than one curl script

Tags: session, curl

i used curl to login a  website. the code is:

```
<?php

$cookie_file    =  tempnam('./temp','cookie');
$login_url      =  'http://bbs.xxxx.com/login.php';
$post_fields    =  'cktime=31536000&step=2&pwuser=xx&pwpwd=111111';

$ch = curl_init($login_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$url='http://bbs.xxx.com/userpay.php';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match("/<li>  (.*)<\/li>/",$contents,$arr);
echo $arr[1];
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

it works fine，but the problem is that when i make it into two files（a.php，b.php）.it does not work.

i make a.php like:

```
<?php

    $cookie_file    =  tempnam('./temp','cookie');
    $login_url      =  'http://bbs.xxxx.com/login.php';
    $post_fields    =  'cktime=31536000&step=2&pwuser=xx&pwpwd=111111';

    $ch = curl_init($login_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

and b.php like:

```
<?php

    $cookie_file    =  tempnam('./temp','cookie');

    $url='http://bbs.xxx.com/userpay.php';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    preg_match("/<li>  (.*)<\/li>/",$contents,$arr);
    echo $arr[1];
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

i first visit a.php,then visit b.php. it dose not work!!!!
can any one help me?
it that different curl scripts can not share session???

Answer (score 0):

In the first CODE you use one $cookie_file for two requests.
You should use same $cookie_file in a.php and b.php.
But you create two different $cookie_file with

```
$cookie_file    =  tempnam('./temp','cookie');
```

You create one in a.php.
Then you create another different one in b.php.